# How to enable Canonical Livepatch Services on official Ubuntu flavors such as Ubuntu MATE?

Tags: 18.04, updates, mate, ubuntu-mate, canonical-livepatch

After recent updates on my Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS I got the new tray icon/indicator:

[image: Livepatch on MATE 18.04 LTS]

When I click on *Livepatch Settings...* it opens *Software & Updates* on the corresponding tab named *Livepatch* but it is not enabled:

[image: Software & Updates]

What should I do to enable it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here we have two problems:

1. *Livepatch is not available for this system*
2. *Gnome Online Accounts is required to enable Livepatch*

To solve the problems we need to install Livepatch as Snap and to install GNOME Online Accounts as deb-package with:

```
snap install canonical-livepatch
sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts gnome-control-center --no-install-recommends
```

and reboot.

On next opening of *Software & Updates* the *Livepatch* will welcome us to *Sign in*:

[image: Livepatch Sign in]

but the corresponding part of GNOME Control Center will not open on MATE session.

To open it we need to pass environmental variable to GNOME Control Center:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center online-accounts
```

and setup Ubuntu One account from here.

Then open Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) again, navigate to *Livepatch* tab and click on *Sign In...* button, confirm your account and use Livepatch:

[image: Livepatch is enabled]

Note: it is free for 3 machines, buy more from corresponding [Canonical Livepatch Service](https://www.ubuntu.com/livepatch).

---

From [Marco Sulla's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145623/how-to-enable-canonical-livepatch-services-on-official-ubuntu-flavors-such-as-ub/1145624?noredirect=1#comment2133059_1145624) we have the following solution for Lubuntu. Here reinstallation of `gnome-control-center` is needed. To re-enable the LivePatch use commands below

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
sudo canonical-livepatch disable && sudo canonical-livepatch enable $TOKEN
```

You can get your token here: https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

Comment: Thank you. On my OS (Lubuntu 18.04) I just reinstalled `gnome-control-center`, that was removed in a previous `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Don't really know why it's needed. To re-enable it without restarting the system, you can do `sudo canonical-livepatch disable && sudo canonical-livepatch enable $TOKEN`. You can get your token here: https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

Comment: Many thanks for the Lubuntu info. Worked for me.

Comment: I followed instructions without rebooting. I am not sure the Gnome account was necessary, because as the system did its thing, it never referred to the Gnome account. But I was able to sign in on my Livepatch tab. What does the Gnome account do? Thank you for instructions that worked!

Comment: @MarcoSulla - You should post your comment as an answer because the additional information contained within it appears to be helping others getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Marco Sulia](https://askubuntu.com/users/156176/marco-sulla), I have Livepatch enabled without needing to reboot thanks to his comment. It refused to restart the way he described but I restarted it the simple way after stopping it and I didn't have to do the rest of the process and did not have to reboot. Now Livepatch is on!